# textBox to Date MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

Please have at look on my issue.
Background data: ItemB - field with date type, which has YYMMDDHHNN format
inptdate - textBox for input data in YYMMDDHHNN format
What needed, transform  data from String format (inptdate) into Date format(ItemB)

My way

```
Private Sub Idate_AfterUpdate()

    Dim mydate As String
        mydate = "2212131400"
        inptdate= mydate
        Me.ItemB = CDate(Mid(mydate, 6, 2) & "," & Mid(mydate, 4, 2) & "," & Mid(mydate, 2, 2) & " " & Mid(mydate, 8, 2) & ":" & Mid(mydate, 10, 2))
    
End Sub
```

but my code execute with an "Type mismatch"  error

Comment: I think you have the wrong separator?  Use DateSerial and timeserial

Comment: thanks for your contribution, but i do not think so, because I already have the same code in form

Comment: Dates do not have commas - first convert to normal date and then format as you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Format and CDate:

```vb
Dim TrueDate As Date

mydate = "2212131400"
TrueDate = CDate("20" & Format(mydate, "@@\/@@\/@@ @@\:@@"))
```